# JavaFX draw to image

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

Is there any solution, how to draw to image similiar to `Canvas` in JavaFX? Not by pixel, but advanced drawing functions like `GraphicsContext2D` provides. I am trying to create multi layered `Canvas`, and using another `Canvas` component for each new layer seems like a overkill. Or is this the right and only preffered method?

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple [canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) instances (one for each layer), is the recommended way to create a multi-layered canvas (using an [immediate draw API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_(computer_graphics))).  This approach to generating a layered canvas system is documented and demonstrated in the [Oracle JavaFX tutorials: Working with Canvas: Creating a Simple Layer System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/canvas.htm#JFXGR214).

Your other option, might be to not use a canvas at all, but instead use the [JavaFX scene graph](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/scene-graph-tutorial/scenegraph.htm) ([retained draw API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retained_mode)), placing the scene graph nodes to be layered inside of [Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) (one Pane per layer) and placing all of the layer panes inside a [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html).  You can convert the resultant StackPane to an image at anytime by invoking the node [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) API on the StackPane.

> Isn´t Canvas retained API as well? Since all operations all merely put onto the GrowableDataBuffer and rendered on event?

Yes, calling the canvas API immediate draw is a little bit of a misnomer.  It does work as you say.  Nevertheless, I find it useful to conceptually think of the API as immediate draw as that is pretty much how it appears to the developer using the API, it is more an implementation detail that it uses retained data structures to assist with the initial rendering.

As far as I understand the implementation design, when you issue drawing commands to a canvas, the commands will usually be placed in a buffer and the buffer flushed to an image texture when the first rendering [pulse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438) for the canvas occurs.  So the commands are only retained in the internal implementation until the first render event.  If you do issue further canvas drawing commands on a subsequent pulse, those additional commands will be buffered then flushed at the rendering stage of the next pulse.

For example, if you issue 1 million drawing commands for the canvas in a single pulse, then you will see a pause as those commands are buffered and then rendered, but you won't see the screen gradually update one million times, just a single update.  If you issue 10 million drawing commands in 10 pulses of 1 million commands, then you will see the screen update 10 times.  You have to issue an extremely large number of drawing commands to the canvas to see such behaviour.

If you are doing [detailed performance analysis of a JavaFX application](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/2013/connect/fileDownload/session/C3B800733D28DB105AB5FC964843D1AB/CON1905_Heidrich.pptx), it is important to understand the implementation in order to correctly understand the performance results, but otherwise it is not something that you need to worry about.  I is highly unlikely that this implementation detail will have serious performance implications for your project.

Comment: Isn´t Canvas retained API as well? Since all operations all merely put onto the GrowableDataBuffer and rendered on event?